# How to properly define a record with parameters in Agda?

Tags: agda, dependent-type, homotopy-type-theory

I'm using Agda 2.5.3 and the [HoTT Agda](https://github.com/HoTT/HoTT-Agda) library to learn some homotopy type theory. I've defined a simple S¹:

```
data S¹ : Type₀ where
  base : S¹

postulate
  loop : base == base
```

and now I'm trying to define a record type for a function that acts as the circle recursion principle for a type A:

```
record is-S¹-rec {i} {A : Set i} (base* : A) (loop* : base* == base*) : Set i where
  field
    f : S¹ → A
    f-base : f base == base*
    f-loop : apd f loop == loop* [ Path ↓ f-base ]
```

But I get this error:

```
(_A_22 base* loop* f f-base → Set (_i_20 base* loop* f f-base)) !=<
Set (_i_20 base* loop* f f-base) of type
Set (lsucc (_i_20 base* loop* f f-base))
when checking that the expression Path has type
_A_22 base* loop* f f-base → Type (_i_20 base* loop* f f-base)
```

I've tried increasing the universe level of the record with no luck. Any tips on what this message means would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Currently it is a bit difficult to see what is the problem. Could you:
1. Please try again with a more recent version of Agda, e.g. 2.6.0.1
2. If it still doesn't work, please make sure your code is self-contained so we can try ourselves to see what the problem is

Comment: Unfortunately 2.5.3 is the latest supported version by the HoTT library. I could try and not use it but it's where the definitions of `==` and `_==_[_↓_]` come from and I don't think they're easily replicable.